# use regular expression to find and replace but only every 3 characters for DNA sequence

Tags: regex, replace, character

Is it possible to do a find/replace using regular expressions on a string of dna such that it only considers every 3 characters (a codon of dna)  at a time.

for example I would like the regular expression to see this:
dna="AAACCCTTTGGG"
as this:
AAA CCC TTT GGG

If I use the regular expressions right now and the expression was
Regex.Replace(dna,"ACC","AAA") it would find a match, but in this case of looking at 3 characters at a time there would be no match.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not insert a space at every 3rd place in your string itself (the way you show) and then run your regex?

Comment: I would not use regular expressions for this. It shouldn't be very hard to implement the logic you're looking for with basic operations. Also consider using a `StringBuilder` (if this is C# as I suspect) to avoid having to copy and create a new string for each replacement (since DNA strings can be pretty large).

Comment: In Javascript you could get an array of codons like this: `'dna="AAACCCTTTGGG"'.match(/dna="(\w+)"/)[1].match(/\w{1,3}/g)`, and then you could just join the array into a string with spaces separating the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex? Try this instead, which is probably more efficient to boot:

```
public string DnaReplaceCodon(string input, string match, string replace) {
  if (match.Length != 3  || replace.Length != 3) 
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

  var output = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
  int i = 0;
  while (i + 2 < input.Length) {
    if (input[i] == match[0] && input[i+1] == match[1] && input[i+2] == match[2]) {
      output.Append(replace);
    } else {
      output.Append(input[i]);
      output.Append(input[i]+1);
      output.Append(input[i]+2);
    }

    i += 3;
  }

  // pick up trailing letters.
  while (i < input.Length)   output.Append(input[i]);

  return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I may try this also. I'm not sure which one is faster though.I've never used StringBuilder but I'll check it out.

Comment: Strings are immutable; when you are building a string from pieces then every piece, and every append of a piece, requires the instantiation of another String object. All of this heap allocation and garbage collection can add up over time. In the code above, **if it is acceptable to override the input string in place**, then that would be even more efficient than the StringBuilder, using the built-in indexer for String.

Comment: I'm going to try this solution also.  Are you saying that I can avoid creating new strings and instead just keep replacing the same string to avoid garbage collection problems.

Comment: Yes. StringBuilder supports a wider variety of actions, but if all you are doing is in-place substitutions, you can just use the String indexer like this: `input[i] = replace[0]; input[i+1] = replace[1];`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

It is possible to do this with regex. Assuming the input is valid (contains only `A`, `T`, `G`, `C`):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\G((?:.{3})*?)" + codon, "$1" + replacement);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/m8VQyL)

If the input is not guaranteed to be valid, you can just do a check with the regex `^[ATCG]*$` (allow non-multiple of 3) or `^([ATCG]{3})*$` (sequence must be multiple of 3). It doesn't make sense to operate on invalid input anyway.

### Explanation

The construction above works for any codon. For the sake of explanation, let the codon be `AAA`. The regex will be `\G((?:.{3})*?)AAA`.

The whole regex actually matches the **shortest** substring that ends with the codon to be replaced.

```
\G            # Must be at beginning of the string, or where last match left off
((?:.{3})*?)  # Match any number of codon, lazily. The text is also captured.
AAA           # The codon we want to replace
```

We make sure the matches only starts from positions whose index is multiple of 3 with:

- `\G` which asserts that the match starts from where the previous match left off (or the beginning of the string)
- And the fact that the pattern `((?:.{3})*?)AAA` can only match a sequence whose length is multiple of 3.

Due to the *lazy quantifier*, we can be sure that in each match, the part before the codon to be replaced (matched by `((?:.{3})*?)` part) does not contain the codon.

In the replacement, we put back the part before the codon (which is captured in capturing group 1 and can be referred to with `$1`), follows by the replacement codon.

Comment: Wow. A proof and explanation and speed test. Amazing. The Regex seems like magic so it may take some time to digest your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be an issue when trying to do multiple replacements. In succession I want to replace TTC with TTT, AGT with CCC and AAG with AAA. I start off with AAGTCT and first replace with TCT with TTT then it reads AAGTTT then for some reason it matches AGT and replaces it even though it is not a codon. The codons are AAG and TTT at that point.

Comment: Also I am using multiple replacements like TTG|TTC would be replaced by TTT. I wonder if that's causing the problem.  Like "\G((?:.{3})*?)TTG|TTC"

Comment: @danielsavage: I repeat; this problem is not well-suited to a regex solution (even if one should exist).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I am sure the regex solution works correctly. Maintainability is another story... I think the complexity should be the same as your solution, minus compiling the regex part.

Comment: @danielsavage: The solution is designed to work with a single codon. For many codons, it depends - is the mutation happening one after another (and previously mutated codon is mutated again) or all the mutation happens at once (and a codon is mutated once if it matches the rule).

Comment: @nhahtdh It's kind of like a synonym replacer. It replaces synonyms  with a base word. In terms of speed and such are the simple operations faster? I thought maybe the Regex library was more optimized for find/replace type of operations.

Comment: @danielsavage: Usually, regex is a bit slower, but you should time it to see how slow it actually is (with the actual input size). If you need to be extremely efficient, then regex is usually not the choice. The advantage of regex is that in a number of cases, writing a single line of regex code is much more clearer and less code to write than writing a wall of code to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE***

***As explained in the comment, the following is not a good solution! I leave it in so that others will not fall for the same mistake***

You can usually find out where a match starts and ends via `m.start()` and `m.end()`. If `m.start() % 3 == 0` you found a relevant match.

Comment: No, this is not a good solution. For example, given `CAAAAA` and you want to find `AAA`. The engine will return **a single match** at index 1, which is invalid according to your method. While there is actually one valid match at index 3 (not return by engine, since the `A` is consumed in the match at index 1).